# C# Unable to create a constant value of type Data.Awards

Tags: c#

```
var awards = proxy.Awards.Where(c => c.Sender_Id == Id || c.Receiver_Id == Id).ToList();    
var Comments = (from comment in proxy.AwardsComments join award in awards on comment.AwardId equals award.Id select comment).ToList();
```

i'm using the above code to get the comments related to the awards but i'm getting the error `Unable to create a constant value of type Data.Awards. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you rewrite your LINQ query as below and give it a go:

```
var comments = (from comment in proxy.AwardsComments
               join award in proxy.Awards.Where(c => c.Sender_Id == Id 
                                                  || c.Receiver_Id == Id)
               on comment.AwardId equals award.Id 
               select comment).ToList();
```

From your setup I assume that you might use an ORM (e.g. Entity Framework). Then you fetch some of the data in memory, by demanding the immediate execution of the query in the right side of `awards` (by calling `ToList`). After then you want to perform a join of the fetched rows with some rows in the database. Quite probably the latter is the problem and the reason you get this error message is the fact that your query cannot be translated to an equivalent SQL query that would be executed to your database.

By using the above query the required SQL statement would be created and the corresponding rows would be fetched out of the database.

Comment: @MohammedEhab You are welcome ! I am glad that I helped.